# Icons in a Symfony ChoiceType

Tags: php, symfony, twig, symfony-forms

I have a Symfony Form and I try to display a `SelectField` with different Icons.

My ChoiceType looks like this

```
  ->add('icon', ChoiceType::class, [
            'choices'  => [
                '&#xf26e;' => '',
                '&#xf170;' => '',
            ],
            'mapped' => false,
        ])
```

My CSS looks like this

```
select { font-family: 'FontAwesome', Verdana }
```

When I render a normal select div it works very well and i can see the icons.

But when   try it via the Symfony Form it does not work. I have already read other Threads with the same problem. One solution was the to set the auto-escape of twig to false and try to work with the raw tag. But still i just see the pure text "" and not the Icons in the Select Box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option, you can do this using the `html_entity_decode` function

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    // prepare an array with icons
    $icons =  [
        '&#xf042;',
        '&#xf170;',
    ];
    
    // decode our icons
    $icons = array_flip(array_map('html_entity_decode',$icons));
    
    // add field to formBuilder
    $builder->add('icon', ChoiceType::class, [
        'choices'  => $icons,
        'mapped' => false,
    ]);

}
```

add css

```
select { font-family: 'FontAwesome'}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This works perfectly!
Now i have a second problem. I want also render the labels of my chartJs Chart as Icons.
So i set the label to  an array filled with &#xf042;....
I set the Font of the Chart and the Label to my Iconfont
But still when i render the Chart i just see the hardcoded &#xf042; as labels and not the Icons. You maybe have any suggestion?

Kind regards,
Magnus